# Best way to handle early returns in chains of promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

What's the best way to handle early returns in Bluebird without throwing an error. For example, I have a conditional in the following:

```
things.find(1)
  .then(function(thing) {
    if (thing.condition === true) {
      return thing
    } else {
      // early return?
    }
  })
  .then(function(thing) {
    return doStuff(thing)
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

Once a `.then` chain is formed, its natural behaviour is to run progressively to completion as each of its stages settles.

For an "early return" (not a good phrase but we know what you mean), you have three options :

- throw an error, or return a rejected promise, to bypass all success handlers until the next catch (or the end of the chain)
- return a promise that is guaranteed never to settle - eg `return new Promise()`
- compose the `.then` chain responsively (Esailija's answer)

Answer (score 2):

```
things.find(1).then(function(thing) {
  if (!thing.condition) return;
  return doStuff(thing)
    .then(...);
    .then(...);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to achieve this without nesting? I was hoping to uses promises to avoid callback hell.

Comment: How is this a callback hell?

Comment: Tip: `things.find(1).then(function(thing) { if (!thing.condition) return; return thing.then(doStuff); })` has nicer indentation.

Comment: @Bergi, in your tip, is `thing` thenable?

Comment: Sorry, not just the tip, Esailija's answer too.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Uh, I already wondered, but just copied it. Probably it should be `Promise.resolve(thing).then(doStuff)` or `doStuff(thing)`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 your original code only makes sense if thing is a promise - otherwise why would you cut the then handler by returning `thing`