# cancel angular promise without invoking .error()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Is it possible that I cancel a promise without going to it's error scenario ?

```
var a = b.getPromise().
success(function(){
    //whoa
})
.error(function(){
    //no!!!
})

 b = {};
 b.getPromise = function(){
     return $q.defer().promise;
 }
```

Comment: There is no `.success` or `.error` in a `$q` promise - there's `.then` and `.catch`. Also, there's no notion of "cancelling" of a promise.

Comment: you can not cancel a promise but you can always stop propagation of promise depending on conditions

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525354/best-way-to-handle-early-returns-in-chains-of-promises/29558623#29558623)

Comment: @NewDev yes there is, you can cancel a promise in Angular in some scenarios - for example in `$http` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, yes, of course, but that is cancelling the task associated with the promise - the HTTP request in your example - which rejects the promise, not "cancelling the promise". I have a feeling that the OP meant to ask about `$http` (given reference to `.success`/`.error` and the cancellation), and I hoped he would correct it based on my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can cancel Angular `$q` promises at all?

But if you don't want to call either handlers, you will have to return a promise that is forever pending. Not that I would recommend that…

A better idea would be to cancel so that the error path is activated, and you handle the cancellation case there explicitly.